# Use classes static method when you only have the type name of the class as a string

Tags: c#, reflection, types, casting, static

I am wondering if it is possible to use a classes method when you only know the classes name by it's string value.

Let's say I have a class and within class I have a static method like

```
public class SomeClass 
{
    public static string Do()
    {
         //Do stuff
    }
}
```

And when using class I want to something like

```
string str = (GetType(SomeClass)).Do();
```

When using the method I want to give the name of the class as string like I want to give SomeClass as a string.

Comment: See [`MethodInfo.Invoke` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.invoke(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: You already tagged the question with reflection, and that's what you're after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var t = Type.GetType("MyNamespace.SomeClass");
var m = t.GetMethod("Do");

m.Invoke(null, new object[] { /* Any arguments go here */ });
```

Comment: When I try this, or even Type t = Type... GetMethod seems to have no definition.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Type.GetMethod`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getmethod.aspx) to get the method info object of the method, then call [`MethodInfo.Invoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh.aspx) to execute it. For static methods, pass null as the first parameter (the object value):

```
Type type = typeof(SomeClass);
type.GetMethod("Do").Invoke(null, null);
```

If you don’t know the class name at compile time, you can also use [`object.GetType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype.aspx), [`Type.GetType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.gettype.aspx) or [`Assembly.GetType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.gettype.aspx) to get the type object at runtime (depending on what information you have available). Then, you can use it in the same way:

```
Type type = someObject.GetType(); // or Type.GetType("SomeTypeName");
type.GetMethod("Do").Invoke(null, null);
```

To be on the safe side, make sure to check whether `GetMethod` actually returns a method, so you have some confirmation that the method exists on that type then.

Comment: Op knows class name at runtime only.

Comment: If the OP knows enough at compile time to write `typeof(SomeClass)`, they might as well just write `SomeClass.Do()`.

Comment: @Asad I think poke misread the question as if OP knows the class at compile time but not the method.

Comment: Thanks for your corrections, I updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @poke visual studio cannot find the definition GetMethod of the type Type. I am confused.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to use reflection throughout; for example:

```
object result = Type.GetType(typeName).GetMethod(methodName).Invoke(null, args);
```